# Configure interface to get address via dhcp Solaris

Tags: solaris, dhcp

I had the interface configured with static IP. Configuration was located in `/etc/hostname.{if-name}` to configure interface after boot.

Now I need to configure it using DHCP. I created file /etc/{if-name}.dhcp
Then I cleared `/etc/hostname.{if-name}` and past here only hostname.

After boot it doesn,t managed with dhcp but gets old config which was in `/etc/hostname.{if-name}`

I'm using Solaris 11

Comment: Looks like Oracle has introduced more (newer! betterer!) commands to configure your Solaris 11 networking. Try looking at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-admin/s11-network-config-1632927.html for more information.

Comment: A quick look at the manual will give you the answer. Hint: look at ipadm man page. Management via files is not longer applicable with Solaris 11.